# 502 error after deployment to Azure

Tags: azure, publishing, deployment

We have had an automated deployment process that has been working well for ages deploying our Sitecore 8.2 Update 5 site to Azure. Yesterday, a deployment failed to our test environment with the CD instance of the site returning:

> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a
>   gateway or proxy server

All Sitecore URLs are returning 502, the only URLs being served are static images.

At the end the only way to fix the issue was restoring the Sitecore web database to a restore point before the deployment. So it appears the web database somehow got corrupted.

Has anyone else experienced this? I would like to find the root cause of the problem so it doesn't occur in our production environment.

Comment: Is your instance behind a load balancer?  I've seen this issue during initial spin up if it takes too long the load balancer thinks the server is offline and kills the connection.

Comment: Closing this as abandoned. 502 problems (though not directly related to the rollback problems of this post) have been discussed and answered in detail here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19466/502-web-server-received-an-invalid-response-while-acting-as-a-gateway-or-proxy