# Maintenance Page in Sitecore Azure PaaS

Tags: azure, sitecore-api, paas

I have a Sitecore 9.0.2 environment in Azure PaaS. It is connecting to different third party services to get and data. Whenever third party update their system or make any new release our portal goes down or start showing the blank page as data is coming from third party. I want to show a Maintenance page on the site whenever third party is upgrading their environment. Third party in advance provide the time line for their system upgrade.

I tried to create a "app_offline.htm" page but it  is not working in Azure PaaS and throwing following exception.
"502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server."

Please help me with this issue.

Thanks in Advance
Alok...

Answer (score 2):

The 502 error is a common occurence on Azure PAAS whenever internal Sitecore is booting up after deployment or any other issues. This SSE question details out the different reasons for the same.

[502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19466/502-web-server-received-an-invalid-response-while-acting-as-a-gateway-or-proxy)

For the maintenance page , in Sitecore webroot , you can use the default.htm page and map it in either a diffrent website from the load balancer.